# Having Trouble Using Insertion Sort with JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, nullpointerexception

```
public class ReverseList extends HttpServlet {

   public static void sort(int arr[]) {
      int N = arr.length;
      int i, j, temp;
      for (i = 1; i< N; i++) {
          j = i;
          temp = arr[i];
          while (j > 0 && temp < arr[j-1]) {
              arr[j] = arr[j-1];
              j = j-1;
          }
          arr[j] = temp;
      }
  }

  private void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
      String jsonStr = "";
      if(br != null){
          jsonStr = br.readLine();
      }
      StringReader strReader = new StringReader(jsonStr);
      JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(strReader);
      JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
      JsonArray inArray = obj.getJsonArray("inList");
      int data [];
      for (int i = 0; i > inArray.size(); i++) {
         data = new int[inArray.getInt(i)];
      }
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      this.sort(data);
      long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
      JsonArrayBuilder outArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
      for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
         outArrayBuilder.add(data[i]);
      }
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("{ \"outList\" : " + outArrayBuilder.build().toString()+"\n");
      out.println("algorithim: Insertion Sort\n Execution time:"+ elapsedTime+"}");
  }
}
```

I am trying to convert the JSON Array into an int[], sort the int[], then output it as JSON with the time it took the sort to execute. The error I'm receiving is a NullPointerException.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException   
 csi403.ReverseList.sort(ReverseList.java:23)   
 csi403.ReverseList.doService(ReverseList.java:99)   
 csi403.ReverseList.doPost(ReverseList.java:44)
```

This is my first time using a servlet and I don't have an efficient way to make corrections and compile for errors. I am using a combination of Amazon Web Services- Elastic Beanstalk, Postman, and maven to create an HTTP endpoint. So, the question is twofold. Why am I running into this error? And, is there an easier way to compile this code and make corrections. I have heard about a tool called cURL but am unsure how it would be any different from what I am doing now. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You start by putting up a [mcve]; for example: you try to run all of this ... locally. Make sure that your code to read in json, and sorting that works. And forget about all the other things that add complexity until you are 110% sure that JSON parsing, sorting, on your **local** machine works flawlessly.

Comment: Your stacktrace tells you where the exception is. Please provide it in your question

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Can you recommend any resources for me to use to learn how to set everything up on my local machine? I will be doing more assignments similar to this. And what you're suggesting seems like the perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: You're just running a web server. But even that does not matter. Make a text file for JSON that you expect, read the file and parse it. Forget Amazon and postman and the web server

Comment: @cricket_007 the code was built successfully through Maven. But, the issues arise through Postman, when I make a Post. Here is the error report from Postman.                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
 csi403.ReverseList.sort(ReverseList.java:23)
 csi403.ReverseList.doService(ReverseList.java:99)
 csi403.ReverseList.doPost(ReverseList.java:44)

Comment: Postman isn't a Java app. Why are you returning a stacktrace to postman?

Comment: So, I ask, what do you think 'int i = 0; i > inArray.size()' means?

Comment: "what do you think 'int i = 0; i > inArray.size()' means?" That was a mistake. And it ties back into what you and the earlier responder said about simplifying the program and making sure everything regarding reading and parsing the JSON is working.

Answer (score 1):

The way you create and populate your array before sorting may be near of:

```
int[] data = new int[inArray.size()];
for( int i = 0; i < inArray.size(); i++) {
   data[i] = inArray.getInt( i );
}
```

To sort an array, you may use [java.util.Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)).

```
Arrays.sort( data, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

For the NPE: the condition `i > inArray.size()` is always false, so the array remains null, and in `sort()` `arr.length;` throw the NPE.

Comment: Might not fix the NPE, anyway, though

Comment: NPE fixed by correctly initializing the array, outside the loop.